# How to fetch related data from one model to another one

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am working on an app with Qt/c++ as controller and QML components as view. The app will show **devices** and **channels** related one to each other in this way:

```
+--------------------+
|      DEVICES       |
|--------------------|
| MAC                |<-----------------------------------------------+
| ...                |                                                |
| ID_CURRENT_CHANNEL |+--+                                            |
| ...                |   |           +----------------------+         |
+--------------------+   |           |     AUDIO CHANNELS   |         |
                         |           |----------------------|         |
                         +---------->| ID                   |         |
                                     | ...                  |         |
                                     | MAC_SOURCE_DEVICE    |+--------+
                                     | ...                  |
                                     +----------------------+
```

So one device could being playing a audio channel, and a channel has a source device.

I know how to expose data from one "domain" to the another one, so I created models for both, channels and devices, and I managed to expose them to QML view. But my dilemma (and question) comes when I want to fetch related data from one model to another and show it using QML components. I find three ways:

- Create a new model mixing devices and channels with roles for all data such as channel id, name, quality, and ... source device name, mac, etc. I don't like this solution.
- Create signals (macSelectedChanged) into view, and load context properties with data (deviceSelected) from controller as response for signal emitted.
- Find data related using javascript into view. I have a small idea how to do it and IMHO it is the most consistely way, but performance would be reduced.

Which of these ways is the best one? Is there other better? I'm looking for a answer in terms of usability and performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need one view then you should have one model which contains data from both sources, so the first solution would be apropriate (I know, little overwhelming). If you need to synchronise two views then second solution would be ok IMHO.

Comment: @Bodgan Thank you for your comment. I will take both ways: build simple models when I want show both and relate one each another using a _selectedChanged_ signal; and build complex models when I want show just one of them with the whole info. 
Post your comment as answer if you want some repo.